# Flutter Dart Keys, Initialization, Constructors

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, nullable-reference-types

I am a (relative)beginner, and found this 2-year-old code on the Internet.

The problem is that VS Studio shows multiple issuess such as:

lines 86-90,190 "The parameter '' can't have value of 'null' because of its type",

lines 98-100 "Non-nullable instance field '' mus be initialized",line 127 "The argument type 'Widget?' can't be assigned to a Parameter type 'Widget'",

line 243 "A value of type 'RenderObject' can't be assigned to a variable 'RenderBox'"

and line 318 "The argument type 'num' can't be assignet to the parameter type 'double'"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue, brightness: Brightness.dark),
    home: FlightsStepper(),
  ));
}

class FlightsStepper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FlightsStepperState createState() => _FlightsStepperState();
}

class _FlightsStepperState extends State<FlightsStepper> {
  int pageNumber = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget page = pageNumber == 1
        ? Page(
            key: Key('page1'),
            onOptionSelected: () => setState(() => pageNumber = 2),
            question:
                'Do you typically fly for business, personal reasons, or some other reason?',
            answers: <String>['Business', 'Personal', 'Others'],
            number: 1,
          )
        : Page(
            key: Key('page2'),
            onOptionSelected: () => setState(() => pageNumber = 1),
            question: 'How many hours is your average flight?',
            answers: <String>[
              'Less than two hours',
              'More than two but less than five hours',
              'Others'
            ],
            number: 2,
          );
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: backgroundDecoration,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              ArrowIcons(),
              Plane(),
              Line(),
              Positioned.fill(
                left: 32.0 + 8,
                child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                  child: page,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Line extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: 32.0 + 32 + 8,
      top: 40,
      bottom: 0,
      width: 1,
      child: Container(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  final int number;
  final String question;
  final List<String> answers;
  final VoidCallback onOptionSelected;

  const Page(
      {Key key,
      @required this.onOptionSelected,
      @required this.number,
      @required this.question,
      @required this.answers})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<GlobalKey<_ItemFaderState>> keys;
  int selectedOptionKeyIndex;
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    keys = List.generate(
      2 + widget.answers.length,
      (_) => GlobalKey<_ItemFaderState>(),
    );
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
    onInit();
  }

  Future<void> animateDot(Offset startOffset) async {
    OverlayEntry entry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        double minTop = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + 52;
        return AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _animationController,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Positioned(
              left: 26.0 + 32 + 8,
              top: minTop +
                  (startOffset.dy - minTop) * (1 - _animationController.value),
              child: child,
            );
          },
          child: Dot(),
        );
      },
    );
    Overlay.of(context).insert(entry);
    await _animationController.forward(from: 0);
    entry.remove();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 32),
        ItemFader(key: keys[0], child: StepNumber(number: widget.number)),
        ItemFader(
          key: keys[1],
          child: StepQuestion(question: widget.question),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        ...widget.answers.map((String answer) {
          int answerIndex = widget.answers.indexOf(answer);
          int keyIndex = answerIndex + 2;
          return ItemFader(
            key: keys[keyIndex],
            child: OptionItem(
              name: answer,
              onTap: (offset) => onTap(keyIndex, offset),
              showDot: selectedOptionKeyIndex != keyIndex,
            ),
          );
        }),
        SizedBox(height: 64),
      ],
    );
  }

  void onTap(int keyIndex, Offset offset) async {
    for (GlobalKey<_ItemFaderState> key in keys) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 40));
      key.currentState.hide();
      if (keys.indexOf(key) == keyIndex) {
        setState(() => selectedOptionKeyIndex = keyIndex);
        animateDot(offset).then((_) => widget.onOptionSelected());
      }
    }
  }

  void onInit() async {
    for (GlobalKey<_ItemFaderState> key in keys) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 40));
      key.currentState.show();
    }
  }
}

class StepNumber extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;

  const StepNumber({Key key, @required this.number}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 64, right: 16),
      child: Text(
        '0$number',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 64,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StepQuestion extends StatelessWidget {
  final String question;

  const StepQuestion({Key key, @required this.question}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 64, right: 16),
      child: Text(
        question,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OptionItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final void Function(Offset dotOffset) onTap;
  final bool showDot;

  const OptionItem(
      {Key key, @required this.name, @required this.onTap, this.showDot = true})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OptionItemState createState() => _OptionItemState();
}

class _OptionItemState extends State<OptionItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject();
        Offset globalPosition = object.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
        widget.onTap(globalPosition);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(width: 26),
            Dot(visible: widget.showDot),
            SizedBox(width: 26),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                widget.name,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 26),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemFader extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ItemFader({Key key, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemFaderState createState() => _ItemFaderState();
}

class _ItemFaderState extends State<ItemFader>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  //1 means its below, -1 means its above
  int position = 1;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _animation;

  void show() {
    setState(() => position = 1);
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  void hide() {
    setState(() => position = -1);
    _animationController.reverse();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
    );
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animation,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, 64 * position * (1 - _animation.value)),
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: _animation.value,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class Dot extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool visible;

  const Dot({Key key, this.visible = true}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 12,
      height: 12,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: visible ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ArrowIcons extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: 8,
      bottom: 0,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: IconButton(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(120, 58, 183, 1),
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Plane extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: 32.0 + 8,
      top: 32,
      child: RotatedBox(
        quarterTurns: 2,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.airplanemode_active,
          size: 64,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const backgroundDecoration = BoxDecoration(
  gradient: LinearGradient(
    colors: [
      Color.fromRGBO(76, 61, 243, 1),
      Color.fromRGBO(120, 58, 183, 1),
    ],
    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the errors are because of null safety features that were introduced to Dart 2.0, read more about it [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety). If you are able to install an older version of Flutter or Dart that code might run fine. In any case most of the errors could be solved by following the IDE's suggested actions. I did you the favor to do it for you, because it was fairly straightforward for most parts. There were some subtleties that were maybe not that straightforward. In any case I believe this is the same code but with the errors and warnings removed:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue, brightness: Brightness.dark),
    home: const FlightsStepper(),
  ));
}

class FlightsStepper extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlightsStepper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FlightsStepperState createState() => _FlightsStepperState();
}

class _FlightsStepperState extends State<FlightsStepper> {
  int pageNumber = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget page = pageNumber == 1
        ? Page(
      key: const Key('page1'),
      onOptionSelected: () => setState(() => pageNumber = 2),
      question:
      'Do you typically fly for business, personal reasons, or some other reason?',
      answers: const <String>['Business', 'Personal', 'Others'],
      number: 1,
    )
        : Page(
      key: const Key('page2'),
      onOptionSelected: () => setState(() => pageNumber = 1),
      question: 'How many hours is your average flight?',
      answers: const <String>[
        'Less than two hours',
        'More than two but less than five hours',
        'Others'
      ],
      number: 2,
    );
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: backgroundDecoration,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              const ArrowIcons(),
              const Plane(),
              const Line(),
              Positioned.fill(
                left: 32.0 + 8,
                child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                  child: page,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Line extends StatelessWidget {
  const Line({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: 32.0 + 32 + 8,
      top: 40,
      bottom: 0,
      width: 1,
      child: Container(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  final int number;
  final String question;
  final List<String> answers;
  final VoidCallback onOptionSelected;

  const Page(
      {Key? key,
        required this.onOptionSelected,
        required this.number,
        required this.question,
        required this.answers})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late List<GlobalKey<_ItemFaderState>> keys;
  int? selectedOptionKeyIndex;
  late AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    keys = List.generate(
      2 + widget.answers.length,
          (_) => GlobalKey<_ItemFaderState>(),
    );
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
    onInit();
  }

  Future<void> animateDot(Offset startOffset) async {
    OverlayEntry entry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        double minTop = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + 52;
        return AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _animationController,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Positioned(
              left: 26.0 + 32 + 8,
              top: minTop +
                  (startOffset.dy - minTop) * (1 - _animationController.value),
              child: child!,
            );
          },
          child: const Dot(),
        );
      },
    );
    Overlay.of(context)?.insert(entry);
    await _animationController.forward(from: 0);
    entry.remove();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(height: 32),
        ItemFader(key: keys[0], child: StepNumber(number: widget.number)),
        ItemFader(
          key: keys[1],
          child: StepQuestion(question: widget.question),
        ),
        const Spacer(),
        ...widget.answers.map((String answer) {
          int answerIndex = widget.answers.indexOf(answer);
          int keyIndex = answerIndex + 2;
          return ItemFader(
            key: keys[keyIndex],
            child: OptionItem(
              name: answer,
              onTap: (offset) => onTap(keyIndex, offset),
              showDot: selectedOptionKeyIndex != keyIndex,
            ),
          );
        }),
        const SizedBox(height: 64),
      ],
    );
  }

  void onTap(int keyIndex, Offset offset) async {
    for (GlobalKey<_ItemFaderState> key in keys) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 40));
      key.currentState?.hide();
      if (keys.indexOf(key) == keyIndex) {
        setState(() => selectedOptionKeyIndex = keyIndex);
        animateDot(offset).then((_) => widget.onOptionSelected());
      }
    }
  }

  void onInit() async {
    for (GlobalKey<_ItemFaderState> key in keys) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 40));
      key.currentState?.show();
    }
  }
}

class StepNumber extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;

  const StepNumber({Key? key, required this.number}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 64, right: 16),
      child: Text(
        '0$number',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 64,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StepQuestion extends StatelessWidget {
  final String question;

  const StepQuestion({Key? key, required this.question}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 64, right: 16),
      child: Text(
        question,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OptionItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final void Function(Offset dotOffset) onTap;
  final bool showDot;

  const OptionItem(
      {Key? key, required this.name, required this.onTap, this.showDot = true})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OptionItemState createState() => _OptionItemState();
}

class _OptionItemState extends State<OptionItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
        Offset globalPosition = object.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
        widget.onTap(globalPosition);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(width: 26),
            Dot(visible: widget.showDot),
            const SizedBox(width: 26),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                widget.name,
                style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 26),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemFader extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ItemFader({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemFaderState createState() => _ItemFaderState();
}

class _ItemFaderState extends State<ItemFader>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  //1 means its below, -1 means its above
  int position = 1;
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late CurvedAnimation _animation;

  void show() {
    setState(() => position = 1);
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  void hide() {
    setState(() => position = -1);
    _animationController.reverse();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
    );
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animation,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, 64 * position * (1 - _animation.value)),
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: _animation.value,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class Dot extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool visible;

  const Dot({Key? key, this.visible = true}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 12,
      height: 12,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: visible ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ArrowIcons extends StatelessWidget {
  const ArrowIcons({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: 8,
      bottom: 0,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: IconButton(
              color: const Color.fromRGBO(120, 58, 183, 1),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Plane extends StatelessWidget {
  const Plane({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Positioned(
      left: 32.0 + 8,
      top: 32,
      child: RotatedBox(
        quarterTurns: 2,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.airplanemode_active,
          size: 64,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const backgroundDecoration = BoxDecoration(
  gradient: LinearGradient(
    colors: [
      Color.fromRGBO(76, 61, 243, 1),
      Color.fromRGBO(120, 58, 183, 1),
    ],
    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  ),
);
```